# How do I create a delay between signal sequences in ReactiveCocoa?

Tags: cocoa, reactive-cocoa

I have three signals which I want to evaluate in sequence with a one second delay between them.

This snippet does what I want, but it's ugly:

```
RACSignal *first = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
    NSLog(@"First!");
    [subscriber sendCompleted];
    return nil;
}];

RACSignal *second = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
    NSLog(@"Second!");
    [subscriber sendCompleted];
    return nil;
}];

RACSignal *third = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
    NSLog(@"Third!");
    [subscriber sendCompleted];
    return nil;
}];

NSArray *signals = @[first, [[RACSignal empty] delay:1.0f],
                     second, [[RACSignal empty] delay:1.0f],
                     third];

NSLog(@"Starting");
[[[signals rac_sequence].signal concat] subscribeCompleted:^{
    NSLog(@"Done!");
}];
```

And it prints out:

```
2013-11-18 17:13:35.326 Starting
2013-11-18 17:13:35.327 First!
2013-11-18 17:13:36.328 Second!
2013-11-18 17:13:37.329 Third!
2013-11-18 17:13:37.330 Done!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is pretty close. You don't need the "spacer" signals, you just need to put the `-delay:` calls on the first and second signals. `-concat:` will serialize the execution of the signals so that each subsequent signal starts only after its prior signal completes, and `-delay:` will postpone the delivery of its signal's completion, thus providing the required delay before the subsequent signal starts its work. You also don't need to hop into a RACSequence and back out, as `-concat:` can take a fast enumeration of signals:

```
NSLog(@"Starting");
NSArray *signals = @[ [first delay:1.0f], [second delay:1.0f], third ];
[[RACSignal concat:signals] subscribeCompleted:^{
    NSLog(@"Done!");
}];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't really fix it. You see, delay only delays the next and complete events. The original signal's executiong block still gets executed.
So if I crank the delay up to ten seconds, this is the log output:

`2013-11-19 09:08:25.748 Starting
2013-11-19 09:08:25.749 First!
2013-11-19 09:08:25.749 Second!
2013-11-19 09:08:35.750 Third!
2013-11-19 09:08:45.752 Done!`

You see that First! and Second! gets printed at the same time. Then there's a ten second delay until the second signal's completed event is let through the delay.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I didn't realize you wanted to delay the *work*, not the events. Would it suffice, then, to put the delay on the first and second signals instead? This would delay the delivery of the first signal's completed event, which might not be what you want, but that would end up delaying the second signal from starting until after the specified time interval.

Comment: Yes that would work. If you'll update your answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a category for Swift for this:

```
extension RACSignal {
    func execute() -> RACDisposable {
        return self.subscribeCompleted { () -> Void in

        }
    }

    func executeWithDelay(interval:NSTimeInterval) -> RACDisposable {
        var signals = [RACSignal.empty().delay(interval), self]
        var delayedSignal = RACSignal.concat(signals)
        return delayedSignal.execute()
    }
}
```

What makes it possible to execute a single signal with a delay by this:

```
signal.executeWithDelay(2.0)
```

To get responses from the signal you can subscribe using the do methods (doNext, doError, doCompleted etc.)